# AHK for selecting Context Menu Option - Not working

Tags: automation, contextmenu, autohotkey

I am trying to create a Hotkey (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>) to do following:

1. **Right Click** at Current Mouse Location. (to bring up context menu)
2. In the **context menu** go to **Second option**. (or any other option)
3. Click **Enter** on that option.

   > ```
   > ^l::MouseClick, right
   > Sleep, 1000
   > Send, {DOWN  2}{ENTER}
   > ```

**Problem:**
The problem is that ONLY the Right Click command works and brings up the Context Menu successfully but **Down** doesn't work at all, so NO OPTION is Selected from the menu.

**Additional Info:**
I found that if context menu is already there and then if I run following script:

> Send, {DOWN  2}{ENTER}

It selects the option Successfully.
But I need both Right Click and Selection of Option to be done by single Hotkey.

*What am I doing wrong ?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare your hotkeys with command in the same line only that line will be executed

```
^l::MouseClick, right  ; only this line is executed
Sleep, 1000
Send, {DOWN  2}{ENTER}
```

Compared to this:

```
^l::
MouseClick, right
Sleep, 1000
Send, {DOWN  2}{ENTER}
return
```

All lines get executed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That saved me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote `MouseClick, Right` in the same line as `^l::`, this way ONLY the first line is executed.

```
^l::
MouseClick, right
Sleep, 100
Send, {DOWN 2}{ENTER}
Return
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would have never knew that. Now I know why most of my Scripts didn't worked as expected.